# Why can't my main code run a custom module properly on Replit?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this code in a module for my discord bot to join a vc:

```
import discord
import ffmpeg
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

async def join(cxt):
  vc = ctx.message.author.voice_channel
  await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

But the main code doesn't run it and whenever I try my !join command it doesn't work. The bot still goes online, it just won't go on a voice channel. The module is commands. Please help!!

Main code:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
import youtube_dl
import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  message.content = message.content.lower() 
  if message.author == client.user:
        return

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`voice_channel` is not an attribute of `Member`, which is the type of `ctx.message.author`. Instead, you want to look for a `VoiceState` in `Member.voice`:

```
async def join(ctx):
  vc = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
  if vc:
    await vc.connect()
  else:
    # user isn't in voice
```

Similarly, you can't connect to a voice channel with `Bot.join_voice_channel`. You need to call `connect()` on the `VoiceChannel` or `StageChannel` object (if it exists, which is why you should check to see if `Member.voice.channel` is `None`.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, however the command !join won't work :(

Comment: @AmberD Are you in a voice channel when you run the command? Does the bot account have sufficient permission to see and join that channel? Have you tried stepping through with the debugger and/or looking at any logs?

Comment: yes all of those things :( I am entering a voice channel and the bot has all the permissions it needs.

Comment: What happens when debugging then? What logs are printed?

Comment: It says the discord module is not found for some reason? Yet it's been connecting to discord just fine.

Comment: File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Comment: That is unrelated to the voice issue then. Make sure you've installed the discord.py package for your current environment. You will want to sort that issue out first, since that is unrelated to the question you posted here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240874/discussion-between-metro-and-amberd) once you have resolved the ModuleNotFoundError.